# Interactions of subclasses inheritance and mutators/accessors

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, mutators

I have a question about Inheritance in Java, I have 3 classes, Parent Child1 and Child2. Child1 and Child2 are both subclasses of the Parent Method.

```
Class Parent
{
   private int money;
   public void setMoney(int a)
   {
    money = a;
   }

   public int getMoney()
   {
   return money;
   }
    public int calculate()
    {
        int x;
        x = getMoney +100;

    }
}
```

Child1 will accept a value from the user and use the setMoney method from the parent class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
Class Child1 extends Parent
{
   public void displayinfo()
   {
       int a;
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       Child2 roll = new Child2();
       a = in.nextInt();
       super.setMoney(a);
       System.out.println(super.calculate());
       System.out.println(roll.calculate());
   }
}
```

My question is how will Child2 be able to access the input values from child1?
I want my child 2 to add an extra operation to the superclass but i get 0 from child2 as if the values were not initialized in the first place

```
class Child2 extends Parent
{
    public int calculate()
    {
        int y = super.calculate() + 100
        return y;
    }
}
```

i am invoking Child1 from main

```
class test extends Pay
{

    public static void main(String arg[]) 
    {
    Child1 a = new Child1();
    a.displayinfo();
    }
  }
```

edit: copy pasta is real

Comment: Can we see your main class or your test class? Where ever you are initializing your child classes and calling your methods?

Comment: return your calculation first and then check

Comment: i noticed the error in my script and fixed it, but the actual code is like this, 2 subclasses, 1 subclass does a computation, the other will accept input and invoke the other subclass with the computation but it the computation subclass returns a value of 0

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have two instances which don't share any state. So, although they're both subclassing from Parent, each instance has its own value for the field `money`. When your instance of type `Child1` calls `super.setMoney(a)` it updates its own internal state. The object of type `Child2` still has its own state, which will only change if you call `roll.setMoney(a)`.